# SDL2 - How to render with one buffer instead of two?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

In SDL2 I want to be able to draw changes to one buffer rather than redraw the whole image to two different buffers as my setup seems to be doing. Below is a really quick test which shows the unwanted behavior:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL.h>

// Compile: gcc test.c -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2


void putPixel(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0,0,width,height, 0);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
        {
            putPixel(renderer,40+x*10,50+y);
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        sleep(1);
    }


    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is two alternating screens. It is obviously using a double buffer which means I have to clear and redraw to get the output I want. After each cycle of the for...loop I wanted to add a line to the buffer - there should have been 8 lines at the end of the program running. In this case I got 4 on one buffer and 4 on another. I don't want to redraw the previous lines again either, hence the need for one buffer:

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Comment: You're better off creating a small compilable sample that demonstrates your issues. It's very hard for anyone to tell what you do, how often you do it, when you do it and so on, with only a couple of lines of code and a lot of textual explanation.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why single-buffering is bad. Offscreen render target is your best shot here.

Comment: @keltar out of interest, what are those reasons? Also, isn't that what i'm doing by using a texture? I'm about to update the question with more code and better layout.

Comment: I've edited question to clarify and to show what I have found so far. Is there a better way to do this? The point of one buffer is so that i'm only making changes to areas of the screen that need updating - I don't want to redraw the whole screen.

Comment: @Phil_12d3 not literally the same. Your texture acts like backbuffer. However, when there is no backbuffer (by-the-book single-buffering, drawing directly on screen), you likely to notice a lot of flickering or other visual defects.

Comment: @keltar It's not direct drawing to the screen I want. I just don't want double buffering. I still want a backbuffer as you put it, but just one. My original approach seemed to give me two, as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: After doing more readying, this does seem the best way to do it. I'm still open to opinion, but i've moved my solution to be the answer.

Comment: @Phil_12d3 in double buffering, you drawing to back buffer (off screen), then swapping buffers. After swap, back buffer becomes front and vice versa, so contents swaps too. This is core idea of double buffering, falling back to single buffer will result in drawing directly on screen. There is also a tripple buffering, but it doesn't make much sense here. Your shadow buffer is just a copy you need; this is the most logical way to do so and it have minimal performance impact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses a texture as a buffer and copies this to the screen when done.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <SDL.h>

// Compile: gcc test.c -I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2


void putPixel(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", 0,0,width,height, 0);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    /* Create texture for display */
    SDL_Texture *display = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, width, height);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, display);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, display);

        for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
        {
            putPixel(renderer,40+x*10,50+y);
        }

        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, display, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        sleep(1);
    }


    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is below:

[image]